# transfer data sheet from Access 2003 to 2013

Tags: ms-access

I tried different ways to open a data sheet that had been created in access 2003 on access 2013 and I got this error "cannot open a database created with previous version of your application".
I also tried to import it to excel and then import it to access 2013, but that's not working cause it didn't transfer all the forms and data completely.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be in the old `mdb` format, right?

As far as I know, you need `Access 2007` or `Access 2010` to be able to open and convert it.